# Permanent GCS objects access from client browser?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am working on a basic Flask application. I have a page where I want to display only a **downloader link** to every files present in my GCS bucket called `twilio-billing`. I tried to use signed-urls but it's limited to 7 days and it should not be public as it's a private document.

What I have so far:

- A service account called `twilio-gcs@mousset005.iam.gserviceaccount.com` with  `Storage Admin`,  `Storage Object Admin` and `Storage Object Viewer` rights
- generated a `json` authentication key for `twilio-gcs@mousset005.iam.gserviceaccount.com`. The file is load on my flask app using `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = "config/gcp.json"`. I has able to upload files from my flask app directly into that bucket already.

Now I want to let the user being able to download his bills. I has able to try two different urls to access an object stored in my bucket:

1. `https://storage.cloud.google.com/twilio-billing/2021-1-Twilio-receipt.pdf`: works but I must be logged in with my own Google account. If not, I am redirected to the gmail login.
2. `https://storage.googleapis.com/twilio-billing/2021-1-Twilio-receipt.pdf`: never worked. getting Error `403` even with HTTP and when I am logged in on my Google Account. `Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.`

Do you have any suggestions?

**web_messaging/blueprints/texting/templates/temporary.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://storage.googleapis.com/twilio-billing/2021-1-Twilio-receipt.pdf">link A (error 403)</a>
    <a href="https://storage.cloud.google.com/twilio-billing/2021-1-Twilio-receipt.pdf">link B (must be logged in to my Google Cloud Account) </a>
</body>
</html>
```

**web_messaging/blueprints/texting/routes.py**

```
# returning the list all of files 
@texting.route("/billing", methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def billing():
    bucket = gcp_storage.get_bucket('twilio-billing')
    for blob in bucket.list_blobs(prefix=''):
        print(blob)
        # will generate my list of link here to render it on my html
    return render_template("temporary.html")
```

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls look into this, it might help

Comment: Thanks but I forgot to specify that I want permanant link if possible and signed urls seems to  always be time-limited resource

Comment: u can specify the expiry time, days, months, years... not checked, I let you check it out.

Comment: `storage.objects.get` u need to add this as part of your IAM role.

Comment: I tried your solution, maybe there is no other option but with the signed-urls I am getting `Max allowed expiration interval is seven days 604800`

Comment: The client account should be provided access either by his user account or service account(if many users, this is the way to go) that you can share, couldn't find any other way. or else if you don't care who can access it (bad idea for your case) u can make it public anyone with link would be able to access.

Answer (score 0):

You can set object access to the public. Please refer this google cloud storage documentation, https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-public-data.

Comment: I should have specify it but since it's billing, it should not be public. I do believe there is some kind of solutions but was not able to figured it out yet

Comment: It seems that you require (1) access limited to a subset of folks, that implies some form of authentication, (2) you want the URL to be stable, long-lived.  To make (2) and (1) work you need authentication + access control implemented by something other than the URL itself.  Otherwise a leaked URL grants access to anybody who has it, forever. 
 That suggests you need to authenticate your users with one of the authentication mechanisms supported by GCS *or* you implement some kind of front end that enforces your own authentication. If I misunderstood, can you clarify your requirements?